# Selecting a specific column in a row associated with a specific id

Tags: php, mysql

I am running into a little trouble here, I did some searches on Google and Stackexchange to see if someone else had answered this before but it didn't turn up useful content so I am asking for some assistance. I have a column name that does exist in the database however, for some reason the query to MySQL keeps saying that the index by that column name does not exist (Undefined index:) is what I am getting but it is defines in the table so I thought maybe I could go about this another way by requesting the id first, then fetch associated column_name value with that specific id row. Then I want to return that to the variable $column_name to make use of the variable in my next query. Normally when I do $id = $_REQUEST['id']; I get the current id for the item being rendered in the browser. But this "column_name" keeps returning an undefined index error. Yet it exist in the DB just as the ID column does. Why can I call on one and not the other?

How can I call on the specified column_name associated with the id in $_REQUEST['id']; global variable?

In the DB you find:

```
id = "Value"

itemId = "Item ID"

CategoryName = "Category"
```

If I request ID 1, how can I fetch the associated CategoryName with that ID?

Thanks for your help!

```
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

           if(!empty($id)){
               $column_name = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT column_name FROM table   //That is directly associated with $id");
           }
```

Comment: Post your DB structure as well.

Comment: You got `undefined index` from mysql or PHP ?

Comment: @frz3993 I think I am getting it from php because it is happening at the point where I am doing the $categoryName = $_REQUEST['CategoryName']; So I am looking for a different way since it does seem to $_REQUEST['id']; just fine.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, see if it contains the CategoryName with the same case.

Comment: @frz3993 No it seems to return the id instead of the value in the category name column which doesn't make sense to me. I am not requesting the id.

Comment: That just means , it does not get send to the server. How do you do the request from browser to server ? With get or post method.? I'm suspecting you have a misconception of how things work.

Comment: I am doing it with $_REQUEST[categoryName]; while storing it in a variable. Usually it works just fine when I request the id.

Comment: Does your url have something like `?id={some id here}` but no `categoryName={some category name}` ? `$_REQUEST` will contain all contents of `$_POST`,`$_GET`, and `$_COOKIES`.

Comment: @frz3993 yes my URL does contain a ?id=2 I would like to have an option to go back to the category list but I need to gather the current category name into a variable to use it in the next query to allow the link to generate dynamically based on the category list they were just on. And yes it does not contain categoryName={some category name}

Comment: @frz3993 Thanks for your last question. You helped me realize what was wrong and I added the necessary text to the link so that now it displays in the URL categoryName={Some category name} then the $_request variable was able to access the name and store it in the variable for the next function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this thanks to @frz3993 by adding categoryName={some cat name} to the dynamically generated link redirecting to the page in question while also making the category value dynamically generated as well.

The previous page needed a modification to the link such as

```
href="DynamicallyGeneratedLink.php?categoryName=%s&id=%s"
```

This was able to make the category name available for the $_REQUEST[]; variable to then use it to create a new dynamically generated link that would allow the visitors to go back to the previous full list of items in the category without having to use the back button.

Now the following code looks like

```
    function backToCategoryList($dbConnection){

        $categoryName = $_REQUEST['categoryName'];

        if($r = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT categoryName FROM table WHERE categoryName = '$categoryName' LIMIT 1")){
            while($d = $r->fetch_assoc()){
                printf("<a href=\"%s?categoryName=%s\"><i class=\"icon icon-th\"></i></a>", $d['link'], $d['categoryName']);
            }               
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the $id in a `WHERE` clause in the query:

```
$column_name = $this->dbConnection->query("SELECT CategoryName FROM table WHERE id = $id");
```

Also, remember to escape all parameters you send to the databse, without it $id would be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Good luck :)

Comment: I tried it but no luck. I am checking to see if some form of sql join function between the item category and the category list can help me pull more data than just the category name as I will need some data in a separate table to finish this.

Comment: can you post your relevant tables with some sample data? also I updated my query with correct column name :)

Comment: @frz3993 helped me realize what was wrong in the link and that helped me come up with a solution I then posted.